# If $\sum a_{n}$ is conditionally convergent. For $p > 1$, $\sum n^{p} a_{n}$ is divergent. (true/false)

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $\sum a_{n}$  is conditionally convergent. For $p > 1$, $~~\sum n^{p}~ a_{n}~~$ is divergent.

Is the above statement is true or false $~?$

I think the statement is true. Since, I couldn't find any conditionally convergent series which contradicts the statement.

The statement is true for all $$\sum \frac{(-1)^{n}}{ n^{p}},~~~~~~~~~~ \sum \frac{(-1)^{n}}{ n^{p}} \log n$$ type series where $0<p≤1$.

But is there any general prove for this or some property, so that I would not need to find any counter example$~?$

Comment: You mean conditionally but not absolutelly convergent series?

Comment: Yes $\sum |a_{n}|$ should be divergent.

Comment: if $n^pa_n$ would be convergent, then $n^p |a_n|$ would go to $0$ (as $n \to \infty)$. But we can do: $\sum |a_n| = \sum \frac{n^p |a_n|}{n^p}$, and since that limit, we have for $n>M$ : $n^p |a_n| < 1$, so by comparison test, our $\sum a_n$ would be even absolutelly convergent, so true

Comment: $\sum n^{p}|a_{n}|/ n^{p}$ would be convergent by comparison test with series $\sum 1/n^{p}$, which is contradiction. Thanks @Dominik Kutek

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The claim is true (when $\sum a_n$ is conditionally but not absolutelly convergent). To show that, we'll prove: when there exists $p > 1$ such that $\sum n^p a_n$ is convergent, then $\sum |a_n|$ must be convergent.

So let's take that $p>1$ for which $\sum n^p a_n$ is convergent, that means: $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^p a_n = 0 $ and similarly $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^p |a_n| = 0$, so there exists $N(p) \in \mathbb N$, such that for $n> N(p)$ we have $n^p|a_n| < 1$.

Now look at series $\sum |a_n| = \sum \frac{n^p|a_n|}{n^p} $. We can bound $n^p |a_n|$ by : $M = \max \{1, 1^p|a_1|, ... , N(p)^p |a_{N(p)}| \} $ (there is finite elements in the maximum, so everything's fine).

So by comparison test, $\sum |a_n| < M \sum \frac{1}{n^p}$ which is convergent due to $p>1$.

That means there cannot exist any $p >1$ for which the series $\sum n^p a_n$ is convergent => for all $p>1$ the series $\sum n^p a_n$ must be divergent.

Comment: Fine, except the first parenthetical comment is a best misleading. The _definition_ of "conditionally convergent" is "convergent but not absolutely convergent".